# Segmentation fault when we try to copy array of charcters in function

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm facing seg fault, when i try to copy some value to char array which is passed from main function.

please find attached code sample, please help me where i'm going wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void getVal(char val[]){
strcpy(val[0],"abcdef");      //segfault.
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
char val[64] = { 0 };
getVal(&val[0]);
printf("%s",val);
}
```

posted actual code, when char of array strcpy work fine but through function call it gives segfault. please help me .

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include "ezxml.h"

static ezxml_t root;

void load_xml(char *root_node){

     root = ezxml_parse_file(root_node);
     printf("%p\n",root);
}

void getParamVal(char *objname, char val[]){

  char *char_strip;
  const char *tmp_buf[20];
  int i=0;

  ezxml_t get_child_tmp;
  const char *attrvalue;

  char_strip = strtok (objname,".");
  while (char_strip != NULL)
  {
    tmp_buf[i] = char_strip;
    char_strip = strtok (NULL, ".");
    i++;
  }



  for (get_child_tmp = ezxml_child(root,tmp_buf[1]); get_child_tmp; get_child_tmp = get_child_tmp->next) {
     attrvalue = ezxml_attr(get_child_tmp, "instance");
     if(!(strcmp(attrvalue,tmp_buf[2]))){
     ezxml_t get_child_level1;
     for (get_child_level1 = ezxml_child(get_child_tmp,tmp_buf[3]); get_child_level1; get_child_level1 = get_child_level1->next) {
         attrvalue = ezxml_attr(get_child_level1, "instance");
             if(!(strcmp(attrvalue,tmp_buf[4]))){       
        ezxml_t get_child_level2;
        for (get_child_level2 = ezxml_child(get_child_level1,tmp_buf[5]); get_child_level2; get_child_level2 = get_child_level2->next) {
          attrvalue = ezxml_attr(get_child_level2,"instance");
                  if(!(strcmp(attrvalue,tmp_buf[6]))){
                       printf("%s\n",ezxml_child(get_child_level2,tmp_buf[7])->txt);
            char s[10];
            strcpy (s,ezxml_child(get_child_level2,tmp_buf[7])->txt);  // fine with local array of char 
            printf("%s\n",s);
            strcpy(val, ezxml_child(get_child_level2,tmp_buf[7])->txt); // problem gives segfault only diff is val is from other function.
                   }
        }
         }
     }
     }
  }
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

  if (argc < 2){
  printf("usage: ./test <xml file> ");
  exit(1);
  }

 struct timeval tv;
 unsigned int seconds=0, mseconds=0;

  char val[64] = { 0 };
  char objname[]="a.b.c.d.e.f.c"; 

  load_xml(argv[1]);

 gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
 seconds = tv.tv_sec;
 mseconds = tv.tv_usec;
 printf("START: [%u][%u]\n", seconds, mseconds);

 getParamVal(&objname[0],&val[0]);  

 gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
 seconds = tv.tv_sec;
 mseconds = tv.tv_usec;
 printf(" END: [%u][%u]\n", seconds, mseconds);
return 0; 
}
```

Comment: You are missing an apostrophe. Replace `val[0]` with `&val[0]`. Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight they need a category, Voting to close as didn't read compiler errors

Answer (score 5):

This is incorrect:

```
strcpy(val[0],"abcdef");
```

as the type of `val[0]` is a `char` and not a `char*`. The compiler should have emitted a warning regarding type mismatch:

```
$ gcc main.c -o prog
main.c: In function ‘getVal’:
main.c:6:5: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘strcpy’ makes pointer from 
integer without a cast [enabled by default]
     strcpy(val[0],"abcdef");
```

Don't ignore warnings and recommend compiling with warning level at maximum and to treat warnings as errors. A segmentation fault is occurring because the value of `val[0]` is, incorrectly, being used as a memory address which `strcpy()` is attempting to write to.

To correct, change to:

```
strcpy(val,"abcdef");
```

Comment: plus: getVal(&val[0]) - getting the address of the first element in an array is the same as just passing the array, val itself

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a pointer to *strcpy*

```
strcpy(&val[0], "abcdef"); // '&' gets the address of firt element of 'val'
```

or write simply

```
strcpy(val, "abcdef");
```